# T&P valve line for hot water heater

Tags: plumbing

[image]
What size Fitting do I need to attach to the T&P valve for my PVC pipe

Comment: Are you trying to use regular DWV PVC, or CPVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three quarters inch is the size

Answer (score 0):

Yes 3/4" pipe will thread onto the t&p valve and it should extend to within 6" of the floor. It should terminate in a conspicuous location so any pressure or temperature dumps will be noticeable. Hardware stores sell tubes made of plastic with a threaded end specially for this purpose.

**This is a drip tube**
[image]www.amazon.ca

Not sure what the official name is but it's colloquially known as a drip tube.